# create multidimensional variables in Gurobi using C++ API

Tags: c++, solver, gurobi

I would like to create multidimensional variables in Gurobi using C++ API, such as x[1,4,5], x[5,7,9]. If I create x variable using GRBVar vars[a][b][c], it may generate lots of useless variables which are not included in my model. How can I do that without generating useless variables?

Comment: "True" so-called "multi-dimensional" variables using the syntax you want to use is simply not possible in C++. Multiple dimensions can only be emulated through trickery.

Comment: You can create a struct with overloaded operator []. And you can simulate your multidimensional variable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I would like to create variable x including two elements given above (thousands of elements in my problem), can you show me a demo code by using trickery?

Comment: @MrBin Can you show me a demo code based on the example given above?

Comment: May be later. I have not my laptop beside.

Comment: @MrBin Appreciate for your help